# how statement is executed in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on C++,

The following is a function call in C++,

```
argument = myFunction(argument);
```

What will be the value of `argument` variable passed to `myFunction()` call i.e. value assigned before call to the function or value returned from the `myFunction()` function call.

Comment: How can you pass the value evaluated after the function call as an parameter without evaluating the function call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to temporal necessity, the value of `argument` before calling `myFunction` will be passed. This is simply because you don't have the return value yet.

The parameters to a function call have to be evaluated before the call. The order of evaluation *between parameters* is unspecified, but you only have one, so it is evaluated. Whatever it is at that point (before the call) is used, then the function is called. When the function returns, after being run, the return value is assigned to `argument`.

Answer (score 2):

+1 - @peachykeen

Also may I add that if `argument` isn't assigned a value before being passed to `myFunction` then depending on the compiler and settings, `argument`'s value may be indeterminate before use.

This means that it's value may not be `null` or zero (depending on type).

Comment: Very good point, so +1 in return. There are quite a few things I didn't touch on; this, race conditions, overloads.

Answer (score -5):

Value assigned BEFORE the call will be used inside the function.

Comment: There is no assignment before the call. That's rather important. The value is read, but it is not assigned.

Comment: Trivial questions are welcome as long as they are programming related. This is not a site where "Google it" is a valid answer.

Comment: will you please elaborate ? Whether there is any assignment or not in both the cases my answers seems correct. The value of the "argument" before the function call will be used inside the function.

Comment: Thanks to @ALL fro Ans and above suggestion, i will keep in mind from now onward while asking for any question.

Comment: @Gerald, You are a senior member of the community, I respect you for that,do you think questions like "How do I declare a integer variable in C?" or "How to define a function in C++ ?" should be allowed here ?

Comment: Saying the value is assigned before the call is both confusing and wrong. Nothing is assigned to the argument, it's used as-is. The only assignment in that line occurs after the function returns.

Comment: how can you say that by just reading a single line of code given by OP ?

Comment: @peachykeen, assignment after the function call is not even in the picture, we are discussing "What will be value of "argument", value assigned before call to the function or value returned from the myFunction() function call. ?"

Comment: @BSalunke - The only problem with seemingly "easy" questions is that they have likely been asked before. If you can't find an existing answer, it is fine to ask your question. We will either answer it or close your question as a duplicate and point you to the existing questions and answers. No problem.

Comment: @amit... if no such question already exists on this site, or you can't find one, then it should be fine to ask it, regardless of how simple. The purpose of the site is to be a one-stop clearinghouse for all legitimate programming questions. Obviously it would be nice for people to do a little research first, but we don't want this to be a place where people are afraid to ask "stupid" questions for fear of being admonished. Some may have a different opinion and that's fine, but such discussions are better suited to comments than part of an answer, as they don't add any programming value.